# Read-only properties of protocols in Swift

Tags: swift

From the "Learn the Essentials of Swift" playground, there's an example protocol:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    func adjust()
}
```

There's a short passage after this example that reads:

> **Note**: The { get } following the simpleDescription property indicates that it is read-only, meaning that the value of the property can be viewed, but never changed.

Additionally an example is given of a class conforming to this protocol:

```
class SimpleClass: ExampleProtocol {
    var simpleDescription: String = "A very simple class."
    var anotherProperty: Int = 69105
    func adjust() {
        simpleDescription += "  Now 100% adjusted."
    }
}

var a = SimpleClass()
a.adjust()
let aDescription = a.simpleDescription
```

However how does this class conform to the protocol? What's stopping me from mutating `simpleDescription`? What don't I understand?

[image: Playground screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way to specify in a protocol that you must have a read-**only** property. Your protocol asks for a `simpleDescription` property, and **allows** but does not **require** a setter.

Note also that the only reason you may mutate `simpleDescription` is because you know your `a` is of type `SimpleClass`. If we have a variable of type `ExampleProtocol` instead...

```
var a: ExampleProtocol = SimpleClass()
a.simpleDescription = "newValue" //Not allowed!
```

Answer (score 3):

Protocols place requirements on object's interface, but do not restrict implementation from providing more operations than that.

In this example, the protocol requires a readable `simpleDescription` property and `adjust()` method. The class provides that, so it conforms to the protocol. In other words, this protocol says implementation must have `get` operation, but it does not prohibit them from also having `set`.

You will not be able to mutate `simpleDescription` via that protocol interface, because it does not provide such operation, but nothing prevents you from mutating it through *different* interface — in this example, the interface of the implementing class.

Answer (score 1):

Found this and thought it may be of interest in addition to the excellent answer already provided:

> If a protocol requires a property to be gettable and settable, that property requirement cannot be fulfilled by a constant stored property or a read-only computed property. If the protocol only requires a property to be gettable, the requirement can be satisfied by any kind of property, and it is valid for the property to be also settable if this is useful for your own code.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: Understood the case, but then there should not be a get set declaration syntax (like below) for protocol poperties, as it will not have any relevance.

protocol TestProtocol {
    var prop: String { get }
    var comp: String { get set }
}

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is wrong:

> Note: The { get } following the simpleDescription property indicates
> that it is read-only, meaning that the value of the property can be
> viewed, but never changed.

The `{ get }` states that any entity that wants to conform to the protocol needs to provide **AT LEAST** a getter for simpleDescription.

A way for the protocol to specify a getter only would be to replace the `var` with a `func`:

```
fun getSimpleDescription() -> String
```