# Xamarin.iOS properties binding issue with { get; } vs { get; set; }

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I have base protocol

```
[Protocol, Model]
interface BaseProtocol
{
  [Abstract]
  [Export("isEnabled")]
  bool IsEnabled { get; }
}
```

and one more, which inherits previous

```
[Protocol, Model]
interface SomeProtocol : BaseProtocol
{
  [Abstract]
  [Export("isEnabled")]
  bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

in inherited one - isEnabled becomes readwrite property, and while generating I'm facing the following issue

`Error CS0102: The type 'SomeProtocolWrapper' already contains a definition for 'IsEnabled' (CS0102)`

Is there anything could be done to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi , have a try with using key words `virtual` in `BaseProtocol` .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Xamarin compiler doesn't see a diference between those two definitions of the iSEnabled properties.

For your information, there's no way to specify in a protocol that you must have a read-only property. Your protocol asks for a IsEnabled property, and allows but does not require a setter. [Read-only properties of protocols in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358518/read-only-properties-of-protocols-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

in your first base

```
virtual bool IsEnabled { get; }
```